# Why instance variables of two unique objects reference the memory location?

Tags: objective-c, object, methods

I'm using Stephen Kochan's examples in his book "Programming in Objective-C, edition 4" to learn the program language using the Windows based GNUstep environment. I'm using the gnustep mysys-system-0.29.0, gnustep-core-0.29.0 and gnustep-devel-1.4.0 installs.

Now to the program in chapter 3 of Kochan's book. When I execute the source code,
I'm getting the same instance variable values printed out for the two unqiue objects,
'frac1' and 'frac2'. It appears that 'frac1' object's memory locations for instance variables numerator and denominator reference the same memory locations for the 'frac2' object.

When I set then numerator to 3 and the denominator to 7 in 'frac2', the numerator and denominator in 'frac1' are overwriten. Why? I do not know why?. I get the same fraction 3/7 displayed when printing unique instance variables for 'frac1' and 'frac2'.

Below is the source program that I've compiled:

```
//========================
// ##copied from "Programming in Objective C" pages 30-44 - edition 4


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


// --- @interface section ----

@interface Fraction:NSObject

 - (void)print;
 -(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
 -(void) setDenominator: (int) d;

@end


//----@implementation----


#include <stdio.h>
@implementation Fraction
//{


  int numerator;
  int denominator;
//}

 - (void)print
{
   NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

 -(void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
   numerator = n;
}

 -(void) setDenominator: (int) d
{
   denominator = d;
}

@end

//--- program section ----


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


   //Fraction *myFraction;

   // Create an instance of a Fraction

   //myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
   //myFraction = [myFraction init];

   Fraction *frac1;
   frac1 = [Fraction alloc];
   frac1 = [frac1 init];

   Fraction *frac2 = [[Fraction alloc] init];

   // Set 1st fraction to 2/3

   [frac1 setNumerator: 2];
   [frac1 setDenominator: 3];


   // Set 2nd fraction to 3/7

   [frac2 setNumerator: 3];
   [frac2 setDenominator: 7];

   // Display the fractions

  // 'frac1' print should display fraction 2/3, however 3/7 is displayed 

   NSLog (@"first print is:");
   [frac1 print];

  // 'frac2' print displays fraction 3/7, as expected.

   NSLog (@"second print is:");
   [frac2 print];

   return 0;
}


//========================
```

Answer (score 3):

You have commented out the `{` and `}` surrounding the declarations of `numerator` and `denominator`.  My guess is you did this because you were getting compiler errors when you left the braces in.

I deduce that Kochan's book is written for programmers using Apple's current Objective-C compiler and runtime, for iOS and 64-bit Mac OS X.  This is also called the "new runtime" or the "modern runtime".  This version of the compiler and runtime has a feature called “non-fragile instance variables”, which lets you put your instance variables in your class implementation, instead of in your class interface.  Kochan's code uses this non-fragile instance variable feature.

The GNU compiler and runtime that you are using don't support this feature.

There is a new GNU Objective-C runtime that does support this feature, but the GNU compiler doesn't support it.  You would have to use Apple's compiler (clang) with the new GNU runtime.  I don't know how easy it is to get that setup working on Windows.

You can learn more about this mess here: http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ

The workaround is to declare your instance variables in your interface.  The answers from Tim Dean and Andrew Madsen show the syntax.

Comment: Great answer, Rob. I knew what was causing the problem when I posted my answer but I had no idea about non-fragile instances and that I even had the option of moving my instance variables into my @implementation. Now that I know this I think I might start moving all my instance variables!

Comment: I ♡ non-fragile instance variables.

Comment: Thanks, it all works now that I moved the instance variables from the implemenatation section to the interface section.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you declare the numerator and denominator values in the @implementation of the class rather than in the @interface. This makes them into global variables rather than being instance variables for you class. Update your interface to be like this:

```
@interface Fraction:NSObject {
   int numerator;
   int denominator;
 }

 - (void)print;
 -(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
 -(void) setDenominator: (int) d;

@end
```

and then remove the declarations from your @implementation section. It should then behave as you are expecting it to.

Comment: Thanks, it all works now that I moved the instance variables from the implemenatation section to the interface section.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Fraction`'s two instance variables, `numerator` and `denominator`, aren't actually declared as instance variables, rather they're being declared as globals. You should declare them in the @interface like this:

```
@interface Fraction:NSObject
{
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
}

 -(void)print;
 -(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
 -(void) setDenominator: (int) d;

@end
```

Global variables can be seen and set by any part of your program. When you declare the variables as instance variables in the @interface section of your class, each instance of the class gets its own set of those variables, and other instances can't see/change them directly.

Comment: Thanks, it all works now that I moved the instance variables from the implemenatation section to the interface section.